# Who are all members of Namikaze clan and is Namikaze clan a descendant of Senju clan?

Tags: naruto

I know Minato (the fourth Hokage) is of the Namikaze clan, but I have never heard of anyone other than him belonging to the same clan. What is the Namikaze clan's history? Is it part of the Senju clan?

Comment: I doubt anything in this regard has been mentioned in the manga.

Comment: Since Naruto is the child of Minato and Kushina, doesn't that make him half Uzumaki and half Namikaze?!

Comment: Not every ninja in the Naruto world comes from a well known clan. Much like Sakura, and (to a degree) Kakashi, Minato most likely enrolled into the academy and became a very strong ninja. However, to say that his family was a normal family may not be fair, because nothing is known about the members of the Namikaze.

Comment: Maybe there is no Namikaze clan. Perhaps it's just some name - Karin and Tsunade are the closet thing Naruto has to a family that's alive, unless you want to go into painful detail about how the Uchiha and Uzumaki are related. Perhaps he is part of the Uzumaki clan - after all he can use sealing jutsu like a pro, aside from the fact Kushina taught him a couple things. And his last name just isn't Uzumaki - maybe his parents did this for safety rasons like they did with Naruto's last name. We may never know.

Comment: What we do know is somehow, Naruto, Tsunade, and Karin are related. Minato has long been dead, and knowing where he came from wouldn't help, even though it would open a new train of thought for him and Naruto and the Uzumaki and Senju clans themselves

Answer (score 8):

Namikaze isn't a descendant of Senju. I think it would have been mentioned in the past if it was, just like how it was stated Uzumaki is related to Senju. The past references has been brought up so many times with Kushina having Senju DNA, and therefore Naruto has it too.

As for all the members, we only know of Minato. No other Namikaze member was revealed in the manga. I haven't watched all the fillers, but there might have been another Namikaze person in there.

Comment: Watched all the fillers. There isn't.

Answer (score -1):

> The Namikaze clan is well know for their speed, as seen by the most well known Namikaze's Minato. Despite his extensive use of the Flying Thunder God Technique, his speed came natural. Members of the Namikaze Clan are gifted with high level of intelligence. Due to their speed and ability to master any or almost all ninjustu, they became a nearly invincible clan. They were even capable of standing up against the Uchiha and Senju to a certain extent. Prior to Minato becoming the Hokage however, this clan gained no recognition.

There are some other members mentioned in [this page](http://narutofanon.wikia.com/wiki/Namikaze_Clan).

Comment: If you'd read the url of the link you shared, you'd no that this information is unrelated to the main manga or other works of Kishimoto related to Naruto. "Fanon" describes some of the popular ideas that some of the fandom accepts as true even if there is no support it.

Comment: I apologize for my negligence @Arcane

Comment: In addition that this is a fan-theory/creation, the linked article also has been deleted though, making this less notable...